# Spring data redis windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, windows-10, redis, spring-data

Привет) хочу в проект добавить redis, который хранил бы uiid для активации аккаунта пользователя, отправлялся бы ему на почту и экспарился через 24 часа. Использую spring boot. Полазив в интернете, не могла не заметить, что redis на винде работает только с докера. Если я настрою конфигурацию как сказано в документации, по стандартному порту 6367 (вроде, но это не важно), заработает ли он у меня вне зависимости от ос?

Так же я зарегалась на redis labs,попросила бесплатную дб на 30 мб, как я могу к ней подключиться из кода? С паролем

Comment: Если вы можете поставить докер на свой компьютер, то значит можете постпаить и Redis как образ докера. Как к нему подключаться читайте в документации Redis.

Answer (score 0):

подключайтесь по оригинальному гайду от redislabs
https://redislabs.com/lp/redis-java/

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(
  RedisURI.create("redis://password@host:port"));
```